# 'BYTE' does not name a type || 'BOOL' has not been declared

Tags: c++, visual-studio, gcc, compiler-errors, g++

When I run "g++" to make JNI I got "does not name a type" error.

```
g++ -shared -o finger.dll FingerPrintJNI.c
```

The following is the error messages

```
In file included from FingerPrintJNI.c:4:0:

IMM64.h:21:2: error: 'BYTE' does not name a type
BYTE Data[MAX_FEATUREVECT_LEN];
^~~~

IMM64.h:26:2: error: 'BYTE' does not name a type
BYTE Data[MAX_INDEXINFO_LEN];
^~~~

IMM64.h:31:2: error: 'BYTE' does not name a type
BYTE Data[MAX_INDEXINFO_LEN_1];
^~~~

IMM64.h:44:2: error: 'BYTE' does not name a type
BYTE kind;
^~~~

IMM64.h:55:2: error: 'BYTE' does not name a type
BYTE kind;
^~~~

IMM64.h:73:2: error: 'BOOL' has not been declared
BOOL *bResult, unsigned int *uiMatchScore, unsigned int *uiHit, Pair_t *hCPairs = NULL);
```

The header file looks something like this. 
( I cannot share the whole code due to security reason)

```
XXX_API char * __stdcall XXXXDCI_GetVer();
```

Here are questions.

1. "BYTE" has been declared as uppercase. 
   does it have something to do with Visual Studio?
2. the header file has "__stdcall". does it mean the header file is C++ ?
3. I need to make JNI with the header file above. what do I have to do? Can I do it via g++ compiler? or gcc compiler? without Visual Studio?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. `BYTE` and `BOOL` are `#defined` in `windows.h` as `unsigned char` and `int` respectively. Either `#include` the `<windows.h>`, possible after `#define WINDOWS_LEAN_AND_MEAN` or `typedef` them yourself.
2. `__stdcall` is the standard calling convention used for WinAPI functions.
3. Check out other answers on Stackoverflow regarding that. No need to replicate what has been detailed elsewhere here.

Answer (score 1):

I had very similar error message (but on linux). I decided to solve it by following recommendation in [google c++ style guide](https://google.github.io/styleguide/cppguide.html#Integer_Types) - to prefer types like **int8_t, uint8_t, int16_t, int64_t etc.**, which are defined in `<cstdint>`. So for BYTE, which is short name for unsigned char I used `uint8_t`. This solution is **applicable on linux and windows** also.